# How to reference a cell outside range using query function in Google Sheets

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to copy cells `B` to `F` to another sheet if the text in cell `J` contains specific text. As an example case, I'm using the query function as:

```
=query('Sheet 1'!B1:J,"Select * Where J contains 'Apples'")
```

and that works fine, but I don't want all cells `B` to `J` to be copied across, **just cells `B` to `F`**.

Comment: Welcome.  Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention:

> ...but I don't want all cells `B` to `J` to be copied across, **just cells `B` to `F`**.

```
=query('Sheet 1'!B1:J,"Select B, C, D, E, F Where J contains 'Apples'")
```